# jQuery cookie toggle

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle, addclass

I'm trying to toggle a class on my body tag while using a cookie to remember the users settings.

Using the jquery cookie plugin this is what i've come up with

```
$("a#switchit").click(function () {
    if($.cookie('viewState')) {
        $('body').addClass('light') 
        $.cookie('viewState', 'true', { expires: 9999 });
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('light')
        $.cookie('viewState', null); 
    };
});
```

I'm no expert in jquery so the syntax and everything is probably wrong, but hopefully you can see what i'm trying to achieve and set me right.

My html:

```
<a id="switchit">Switch it</a>
```

Comment: The looks pretty right to me. What's happening that shouldn't be?

Comment: What's the question?  What's not working? Are you including the `.cookie()` function with a plugin someplace else?

Comment: @idrumgood basically the class toggle 'light' works on the body tag, but when i refresh the page the class gets removed...

Comment: @Sparky672 The question was if there was anything wrong in the code, and if i'm doing it right... No the cookie plugin isn't used elsewhere

Comment: That's not what I meant.  I simply asked if you included the plugin.  You posted code without explaining that you're using a plugin which enables `.cookie()`.  Many readers might not know this.   Also sometimes people ask questions wondering why their code doesn't work when they try to use a plugin function without properly including the actual plugin.

Comment: @sparky672 I did, i said "Using the jquery cookie plugin this is what i've come up with". I didn't realised more detail was needed...

Comment: Again, for the third time... sometimes people come here and say they're using a plugin but they fail to "include" the plugin on their page.  I was simply asking if you remembered to "include" the plugin on your page... `<script src="cookie.js"></script>`.  And sometimes that's just put in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment on the question, your issue is that you need to check for the presence of the cookie and set the class on page load as well as when the button is clicked.

To expand on this: A cookie will be persistent on page refresh (pending you've set the expiration for a suitable time frame) whereas any manipulations you make to the DOM (ie adding a class name to the body) will not persist.

You have it set up correctly for your user to select their color scheme and you are setting your cookie just fine. You just left out the part where you check in advance if they've set it on a previous visit.

So, in your jQuery ready function, add:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie('viewState') == 'true'){
        $('body').addClass('light');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
$("a#switchit").click(function () {
    var isNotSet = $.cookie('viewState') === null;
    $('body').toggleClass( 'light', isNotSet);
    if (isNotSet) {
      $.cookie('viewState', 'true', { expires: 9999 });
    } else {
      $.cookie('viewState', null); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical problem, look at line 2:

```
$("a#switchit").click(function () {
    if(!$.cookie('viewState')) {
        $('body').addClass('light') 
        $.cookie('viewState', 'true', { expires: 9999 });
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('light')
        $.cookie('viewState', null); 
    };
});
```

Just look, are you setting viewState=true when viewState is TRUE. You need to set viewState=true when viewState is NULL.